# How can I save and clear data entered into a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, save, state, uicontrol

For example, let's say I would like to design a GUI with a table that the user enters data into. I then want to have 2 push buttons: one that will save the data currently in the table, and another that will clear the data from the table. Are there any code examples/tutorials that explain in general how I can accomplish saving/modifying the state of uicontrols in a GUI in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doug Hull from the MathWorks has a nice video tutorial showing [how to save and restore the state of a GUI](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/10/how-to-save-and-restore-state-of-a-gui-in-matlab/).

You should also check out [41 Complete GUI Examples](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples) (specifically `GUI_41.m`) from [Matt Fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/17055) on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).

It should be straight-forward to figure out from those examples how to also clear all the data from your GUI.